# SWT JFace: SelectionProvider not working in TabFolder

Tags: tabs, swt, selection, jface

In a GraphicalEditor I created a tab folder:

```
private final String[] tabNames = { "Text", "Image" };

private ResourcesTextComposite comText;

private ResourcesImageComposite comImage;

...

public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    ...
    tabFolder = new TabFolder(parent, SWT.BORDER);
    for (int loopIndex = 0; loopIndex < tabNames.length; loopIndex++) {
        TabItem tabItem = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NULL);
        tabItem.setText(tabNames[loopIndex]);

        if (loopIndex == 0) {
            comText = new ResourcesTextComposite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE,
                    resources);
            tabItem.setControl(comText);
        } else if (loopIndex == 1) {
            comImage = new ResourcesImageComposite(tabFolder, SWT.NONE,
                    resources);
            tabItem.setControl(comImage);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

it has 2 tab items and each item has a composite in it, and each composite has a TableViewer respectively.

I tried this to make each TableViewer the selection provider when the user selects the corresponding tab item (the same function createPartControl of the editor):

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
    ...
    tabFolder.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            int tabIdx = tabFolder.getSelectionIndex();
            getSite().setSelectionProvider(null);
            if (tabIdx == 0) {
                getSite().setSelectionProvider(comText.getViewer());
            } else if (tabIdx == 1) {
                getSite().setSelectionProvider(comImage.getViewer());
            }
            System.out.println("widgetSelected" + getSite() + ": "
                    + getSite().getSelectionProvider());
        }

        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            widgetSelected(e);
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

I hope when I select a row in a TableViewer, the Properties view will show the selected model's properties, I've complete those IPropertySource things and they works well in other editors that has no tab folders, so I think the problem should be in the Selection Provider area.

Any ideas or has anyone encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have multiple selection providers in a view or editor, then you need to use a mediator like `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.SelectionProviderMediator`. Note that it is unfortunately internal, so you need to copy it to your own project

Comment: I think at a given time, I hope only one TableViewer works, so using setSelectionProvider to set only one viewer is enough if possible.